# extract svn revsion number with keyword in svn log

Tags: linux, svn, grep

with `svn log | grep "keyword"`
I can grep the line containing the "keyword", e.g.,

```
svn log -v | grep "recur"
(endless recursion) when deleting an object in the tree.
```

However, how can I get the revision number of this commit?

I am using svn 1.6 (not latest one, which has no svn search)

Comment: Can you just instruct `grep` to add enough [before/after lines of context](http://superuser.com/a/688364)?

Comment: well, that is kind of work around. but still thanks for the suggestions. I really look forward to better solutions.

Comment: You'll get better solutions if you can describe how that doesn't answer your question.  Are you trying to automate this?

Comment: yes. i need a working solution for a script.

Comment: SVN can return logs in XML format (`svn log --xml`), that you can then parse, but SVN does not provide a XML parsing functionality. On Windows you can use PowerShell. What is your operating system?

Comment: linux, so no solutions with windows. thanks.

Comment: You need a working solution for a script. Okay, what should that script do with the data from `svn log`?

Comment: well, i would say, find the occurrence of keyword in the data and find the first occurrence with rxxx before. but how to find rxxx in precedence, i need help.

Comment: Yes, but what should the script do with the data it finds? Write it to console, for the the human to read, or something else?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know that working with the command-line `svn` tools is the way to go here.  Your best bet is probably to use the Subversion library's bindings for a scripting language like Python or Ruby.  You can retrieve a log as an list of objects (one per revision) that have the commit message and revision numbers as members.  Finding what you're looking for would simply involve iterating the list.